# Linear transformation satisfying $T(x+x^2) = 2x$, $T(1 + x) = x^2$ and $T(1) = 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T : P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear transformation satisfying $T(x+x^2) = 2x$, $T(1 + x) = x^2$ and $T(1) = 1$. Find $T(2x^2 + x)$.

I don't know if I'm doing this right.
$T(x^2+x) = 2x + T(x^2) =$ ? which will get me my answer if I add up both transformations?

Answer (score 5):

The key here is to first write $2x^2+x$ as a linear combination of $1$, $1+x$, and $x+x^2$ (one can check that these three polynomials form a basis for $P_2(\Bbb{R})$, so it is possible), and then you appeal to linearity of $T$ to find the image.

Specifically,
$$2x^2+x = 2(x^2 + x) - x = 2(x^2+x) - (x + 1) + 1$$

Now from linearity of $T$, we have
$$T(2x^2+x) = 2 T(x^2+x) - T(x+1) + T(1) = 2(2x) - x^2 + 1 = 1 + 4x - x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$M$ is the matrix of $T$ written in bases $(x+x^2, 1+x, 1)$ and $(1, x, x^2)$. To get the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis, we can first observe, that
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
transforms a vector written in the first of the bases in to the canonical basis. Therefore, the inverse operation will be the inverse of $B$, $B^{-1}$. After computing:
$$
B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, the matrix of $T$ in standard basis is
$$
M\cdot B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To get the result, just multiply it by the vector:
$$
M\cdot B^{-1} \cdot [0, 1, 2]^T = [1, 4, -1]^T
$$
or, in other words, $1 + 4x - x^2$.

While the above answer details what goes on in the solution (and is probably more valuable), this one provides tools to actually solve problems effectively.